# ValidationExpression validation in asp.net for digits and character ( / and -)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I need to write an expression like this **123/12-125  must accept (/ and -)** .

I wrote `ValidationExpression` like this `"^(\d*\/?\d*)^(\d*\-?\d*)$"` but did't work

'/' or '-' will be in the middle of string single occurrence but multiple times, but both are optional

Example:

`12/321/1122122-9-666/9995`

Comment: yes digits compulsory to enter and characters(/and -) are optional

Comment: '/' or '-' wil b in middle of string single occurance but multiple times but both are optional
example
12/321/1122122-9-666/9995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"^(\d+([\/\-]\d+)+)$" **Check This, It works. I have tried this myself**

Answer (score 1):

If all i required and digits count must match:

```
"^(\\d{3}\\/\\d{2}\\-\\d{3})$"
```

If 123/12 is required and -125 is optional

```
"^(\\d+\\/\\d+)(\\-\\d+)?$"
```

etc

In most languages ​​do not have built-in regular expressions people misinterpret the escape character `\`. To properly use it you have to double it to use `\\`. Eventually you get, eg, `\d +`.

Secondly, use * only for things that may or may not occur. For the rest, use +.

And at the end of `^` should be used only at the beginning of "sentence". You can use it in the group as a denial of [^ az], but also should be avoided because they accept "anything that is not ...".

Test your regexp here:

[Robular](http://rubular.com/)

It will show you what exacly you match.

You can also indent match group like this:

```
"^(\d+([\\/\\-]\d+)+)$"
```

This means:

- Should starts with at least one digit
- Should have at least digit, / or -, digit
- It can repeat to infinity but always should have schema / or - and digit

Comment: '/' or '-' wil b in middle of string single occurance but multiple times but both are optional
example
12/321/1122122-9-666/998

Comment: Is it exhausts your question?